# .length cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, string

I have tried really hard to solve this with previous similar answers, but am still nto able to see my problem, hope you can help. My code looks like this:

```
String MyContent =" ";
String nextline = " ";

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);

DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bin);

    while(din.available()>1)
    {
    nextline = din.readLine();

    //Filter out XML headers which are not browser compliant
    if (nextline.length > 4)
        {
        if (nextline.substring(1,5) != "<?xml")
            {
            MyContent=MyContent+ nextline;
            }
        }   
    }

    out.print (MyContent);

in.close();
bin.close();
din.close();
```

And I am getting an error:

```
An error occurred at line: 25 in the jsp file: /MaxiSunReports/DisplayXMLFile.jsp
nextline.length cannot be resolved or is not a field
22:     nextline = din.readLine();
23:     nextline = "THISISATEST";
24:     //Filter out XML headers which are not browser compliant
25:     if (nextline.length > 4)
26:         {
27:         if (nextline.substring(1,5) != "<?xml")
```

Comment: It's good idea, to start using an [Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), such as: [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php), [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/), or [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). All of those three will show you alerts and messages about what is wrong with your code before you even hit "compile/n/run" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is not an field. It is a function, so you have to call `nextline.length() > 4`

Answer (score 5):

First, the method `readLine()` in `DataInputStream` is deprecated.

Second, this method returns a `String`, which doesn't have a `field` `length`. It only has the method `length()`. `length` is a property of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

length is not a property, it is a method..

Use

```
while(din.available()>1)
{
nextline = din.readLine();

//Filter out XML headers which are not browser compliant
if (nextline.length() > 4)
    {
    if (nextline.substring(1,5) != "<?xml")
        {
        MyContent=MyContent+ nextline;
        }
    }   
}
```