# Character array, can't get array length

Tags: java, arrays, char

This is in Java

I'm not sure what is wrong with the arrayName.length in my code, it doesn't work on both occasions

```
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++)
        {

        }
    }
```

These two arrays are char arrays and does not seem want to work with the .length method. It says that "length cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.length cannot be resolved or is not a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236560/length-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Comment: can you show is more code than this.

Comment: sry guys, first time asking on stackexchange, image at bottom

Comment: it's not an array, it's an `ArrayList` - you should import it and call the method `size()` on an instance

Comment: Nice arc theme. I like it :D

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using arrays in your code, you are using `ArrayList`s. They are totally different and have different methods. The equivalent method  to `length` for [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is `.size()`.